# Reusing Ajax Established Database Connection

Tags: php, mysql, ajax, database

Two Files involved:

index.php (html markup, db connection and class object)

getajax.php (db connection, sql + response code)

Need to see how can I eliminate the duplicate connection details off the getajax file and reuse the existing class connection function or contruct on index.

Already using mysql_pconnect for connection reuse on the getajax file and index.

**Should I create an extended class for "getajax" so it extends primary object?**

Trying to avoid overkill on DB when lots of calls are made to sql.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Simply using pconnect is sufficient. As noted in the PHP documentation about persistent [database connections](http://nz.php.net/manual/en/features.persistent-connections.php):

> they do not give you an ability to
>   open 'user sessions' on the same link

That is, simply using pconnect tells PHP to use an existing connection if it's available. Whether or not it was the same connection used by the first PHP call is unimportant.

Make sure you read that PHP manual page - there are some important caveats.

Comment: The event handler calls the server script which in turns returns a response text. My question is mostly to where or not this server processing script could reuse an existing DB opened connection. From your answer it appears that using pconnect should use the same connection again and again. Correct? I still need to specify the database to select?

Comment: That's correct. From the docs: "First, when connecting, the function would first try to find a (persistent) link that's already open with the same host, username and password. If one is found, an identifier for it will be returned instead of opening a new connection." You shouldn't need to do anything other that change your normal connects to pconnects.